# Checking for watch changes after data is set on mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i am trying to edit a component, when i open the component i load his data with mounted like this:

```
  mounted () {
    var sectionKey = this.$store.getters.getCurrentEditionKey
    this.table = _.clone(this.$store.getters.getDocumentAttributes[sectionKey])
    this.table.tableGrid = _.clone(this.$store.getters.getDocumentAttributes[sectionKey].tableGrid)
    this.entered = true
  },
```

as you guys can see i change the this.entered, i tried to track when the elements are loaded so i can start tracking with the watcher the changes on my component.

```
watch: {
    'table.rows': function (val, oldValue) {
      if (this.entered === true) {
        if (val > oldValue) {
          this.table.tableGrid.push([''])
        } else if (val < oldValue) {
          this.table.tableGrid.splice(this.table.tableGrid.length - 1, 1)
        }
      }
    },
    'table.cols': function (val, oldValue) {
      if (this.entered === true) {
        if (val > oldValue) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.table.rows; i++) {
            this.table.tableGrid[i].push('')
          }
        } else if (val < oldValue) {
          for (var j = 0; j < this.table.rows; j++) {
            this.table.tableGrid[j].splice(this.table.tableGrid[j].length - 1, 1)
          }
        }
      }
    }

 data () {
    return {
      entered: false,
      table: {
        rows: 1,
        cols: 1,
        insert: 1,
        key: 'Table',
        tableStyle: 1,
        caption: '',
        hasCaption: true,
        hasHeader: true,
        tableGrid: [
          ['']
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

this is how i get the cols and row when i change it so i can build the table again :

```
tableRows () {
  return parseInt(this.table.rows)
},
tableCols () {
  return parseInt(this.table.cols)
}
```

i am tracking my table cols and table row, it is a number input that i change if i want, the problem is that it enters the watcher before the mounted, i don't know how can i handle this situation any help?

Comment: What is your `data` property?

Comment: edited the question!

Comment: try to test this: `this.$set(this, 'table', ..)` instead of `this.table = ...` and `this.table.tableGrid` same.

Comment: what is the 'table' do i need it?

Comment: like this?     this.$set(this.table, 'table', this.$store.getters.getDocumentAttributes[sectionKey])

Comment: `var clone = _.clone(...); this.$set(this, 'table', clone)` and `this.$set(this.table, 'tableGrid', /*clone for this*/)`

Comment: can you put it as a more detailed answer on the answers maybe, even if it doesn't work, i can't understand very well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that includes a minimal set of features that you are trying to use, and it works as expected. Can you use it as a starting point to recreate your problem?

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: {
      rows: 1
    },
    entered: false
  },
  mounted() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.data = {
        rows: 10
      };
      self.entered = true;
    }, 1200);
  },
  watch: {
    'data.rows': function(newValue) {
      if (this.entered) {
        console.log("Rows now", newValue);
      } else {
        console.log("Not entered!");
      }
    }
  }
});

setInterval(function() {
  ++vm.data.rows;
}, 800);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Since you define `this.table` in your `data` section, it is a responsive variable, so you can set it as you do now:

```
this.table = _.clone(this.$store.getters.getDocumentAttributes[sectionKey]);
```

The question is whether `this.table.tableGrid` is responsive. If it is created by the `clone` above, it is. If not, not. If you don't know, change this:

```
this.table.tableGrid = _.clone(this.$store.getters.getDocumentAttributes[sectionKey].tableGrid);
```

to

```
this.$set(this.table, 'tableGrid', _.clone(this.$store.getters.getDocumentAttributes[sectionKey].tableGrid);
```

(It seems to me that the first `clone` should have done the whole copy, tho.)

Comment: the watcher will just be called after i change something in my number inputs to col and row, instead it keeps adding changes just because i am loading the last rows and cols

Comment: hmmm what is the difference between our solutions, can't see what is breaking my logic :S

Comment: @FilipeCosta I have updated it again. I think it's a good starting point now for you to copy and see if you can get it to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: don't know. since i have the exact same thing for a different context issue